# Send Message to Apache ActiveMQ 5 Loop Error in Windows

Tags: activemq-classic

The error is a loop exception:

```
jvm 1    |  WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:53425 failed: java.io.IOException: Unknown data type: 77
jvm 1    |  WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:53426 failed: java.io.IOException: Unknown data type: 77
jvm 1    |  WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:53427 failed: java.io.IOException: Unknown data type: 77
jvm 1    |  WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:53428 failed: java.io.IOException: Unknown data type: 77
jvm 1    |  WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:53429 failed: java.io.IOException: Unknown data type: 77
jvm 1    |  WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:53430 failed: java.io.IOException: Unknown data type: 77
```

I sent a message from Apache Camel + Spring Batch to AMQ process but i got this loop error (Exception) i have this default configuration in Windows 10:

```xml
    <transportConnectors>
        <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=1994857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=1994857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=1994857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=1994857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=1994857600"/>
    </transportConnectors>
```

Comment: What is the client's connection URL? What Camel component is it using?

Comment: In the domain.xml file in my Jboss i'm using this string <jms-topic name="mensajesTopic" entries="java:/jms/mensajesTopic java:jboss/exported/jms/mensajesTopic"/>

Comment: What does the JBoss `domain.xml` and topic JNDI entries have to do with the client's connection URL and Camel component? I thought were you using ActiveMQ 5.x as your JMS broker, not JBoss. Please clarify. Thanks!

Comment: Im using ActiveMQMessageProducer->org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientProducerImpl@9d65c4b
producer = session.createProducer(getTopic(session, ((Topic) destination).getTopicName())); i send the message with:  
producer.send(msg, DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT, 9, 0L); loop
ActiveMQTopic[mensajesTopic]
org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory: 1 interfaces [javax.jms.Topic]; 0 advisors []; targetSource [org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectTargetSource@3388234e];
DEBUG [17:46:23] (Log.java:debug:92) - Connection: org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnection@2ce695

Comment: I don't really understand the information you've provided here. You've got a couple lines of code plus what appears to be some debug output. However, neither of those things tells me the client's connection URL or what Camel component (if any) you're using. I can see that you're using `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnection` which is from the core JMS client implementation shipped with ActiveMQ *Artemis*. It wouldn't work with ActiveMQ 5.x. At this point I'm completely confused. The information you've provided doesn't make sense, and you won't my questions.

Comment: I got the problem, explain i'm receiving message from Artemis is the reason why use <artifactId>artemis-core-client</artifactId> and <artifactId>artemis-jms-client</artifactId> but i need to send a notification to AMQ is the reason for why use <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId> in my code i'm using javax.jms.MessageProducer with this line to send message to AMQ producer.send(msg, DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT, 9, 0L);   can be de dependency conflict i think

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Things are starting to make some sense. How exactly are you creating the `javax.jms.ConnectionFactory` to send messages to ActiveMQ 5.x?